# Is there a shorter way to write this code, without repeating three times switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Is there a better (shorter) way to write this code? thanks

```
public double getPrice(int day, String currency) throws SecurityException{      
    if(currency.toLowerCase().equals(PriceItem.GBP)){
        switch(day){
            case 1: return getDay1Gbp();
            case 2: return getDay2Gbp();
            case 3: return getDay3Gbp();
            case 4: return getDay4Gbp();
            case 5: return getDay5Gbp();
            case 6: return getDay6Gbp();
            case 7: return getDay7Gbp();
            case 8: return getDay8Gbp();
            case 9: return getDay9Gbp();
            case 10: return getDay10Gbp();
            case 11: return getDay11Gbp();
            case 12: return getDay12Gbp();
            case 13: return getDay13Gbp();
            case 14: return getDay14Gbp();
            default: return 0.;
        }
    } else if(currency.toLowerCase().equals(PriceItem.EUR)){
        switch(day){
            case 1: return getDay1Eur();
            case 2: return getDay2Eur();
            case 3: return getDay3Eur();
            case 4: return getDay4Eur();
            case 5: return getDay5Eur();
            case 6: return getDay6Eur();
            case 7: return getDay7Eur();
            case 8: return getDay8Eur();
            case 9: return getDay9Eur();
            case 10: return getDay10Eur();
            case 11: return getDay11Eur();
            case 12: return getDay12Eur();
            case 13: return getDay13Eur();
            case 14: return getDay14Eur();
            default: return 0.;
        }
    } else if(currency.toLowerCase().equals(PriceItem.USD)){
        switch(day){
            case 1: return getDay1Usd();
            case 2: return getDay2Usd();
            case 3: return getDay3Usd();
            case 4: return getDay4Usd();
            case 5: return getDay5Usd();
            case 6: return getDay6Usd();
            case 7: return getDay7Usd();
            case 8: return getDay8Usd();
            case 9: return getDay9Usd();
            case 10: return getDay10Usd();
            case 11: return getDay11Usd();
            case 12: return getDay12Usd();
            case 13: return getDay13Usd();
            case 14: return getDay14Usd();
            default: return 0.;
        }
    }
    return 0.;
}
```

i'm trying to write this code without repeating switch three times, but i have no idea how i can write this shorter. Maybe return method if i concat parametars. i dont know if is this idea at all possible. thanks for suggestion

Comment: Pasting the code as images are discouraged.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/3358570. 
Add code here and explain a little bit more what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: When i add code instead picture says: it looks like yout post is mostly code; please add some more details

Comment: You can use a `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: Q: A better way? A: Yes.  Q: Shorter? A: Maybe.  What do those `getDayNxxx` methods do?

Comment: getDaysNxxx return price for that day and currency

Comment: I mean, do they _calculate_ anything, or do they just each return a hard-coded number?

Comment: @Kevin Anderson sry, i didnt figured out first time what you mean. i return only number which was previously collected from the file.

Comment: @byte perhaps you need to enclose the whole picture and we can make the whole logic cleaner and easier. It looks more complicated than it should be.

Comment: So if the numbers were collected from a file, where have they been stored?  You should just be able to get the numbers directly from the storage place instead of making a separate method to retrieve every possible combination of day and currency type.

Comment: Your problem isn't the `switch-case` - it's those methods `getDayXXX`. Replace them with one method accepting the day and currency symbol as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

```
Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(nameOfField);
return (Double) field.get(this);
```